# Structural Adjustment Programs question

Tags: macroeconomics

I am writing a paper about SAPs. Its very controversial because of all the imposed policies on the country they are lending money to, the countries tend to get poorer instead of richer. I am still a bit confused though, the IMF certainly isn't a charity organization and they wont just give away money and forget about debts etc.
On the other hand I tried researching to find any country that benefited from SAPs and I failed. If nobody ever benefited except the loaners then isn't this a very obvious scam?

My questions are the following: Was any SAP ever successful? Is there anything good about them? And do the Netherlands have any official stance regarding SAPs?